# While running return statement i got some bad output dont know why?

Tags: python

When i run this code:-

```
def get_formatted_name(firstname,lastname):
    fullname=(firstname+" "+lastname)
     return fullname
get_formatted_name('aman','soni')
print(get_formatted_name)
```

I get this output:-

```
<function get_formatted_name at 0x784b300b80>
```

[Program finished]

Comment: `print(get_formatted_name)` You logged the function, not the result of the function call.

Comment: I think you mean `print(get_formatted_name('aman','soni'))`.

Answer (score 1):

That's the output you get when you try to print a literal function. `print(get_formatted_name)` is not the way to print the results of that function. `get_formatted_name` just means the function itself. To print the *returned value*, you have to either save the value of the function and print it:

```
formatted_name = get_formatted_name('aman','soni')
print(formatted_name)
```

Or, just print the result directly:

```
print(get_formatted_name('aman','soni'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the function you have just defined. To print the result of calling the function with the given arguments, try:

```
def get_formatted_name(firstname,lastname):
    fullname=(firstname+" "+lastname)
     return fullname

print(get_formatted_name('aman','soni'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function but not assigning its output to any variable.
Two ways to solve this:

```
print(get_formatted_name('aman','soni'))
```

Or

```
printableName = get_formatted_name('aman','soni')
print(printableName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are printing the function not what it returns.
What you should do instead is:

```
fullname= get_formatted_name('x', 'y')
print(fullname)

OR

print(get_formatted_name('x', 'y'))
```

This call the function and print its output not the function type